# Closure compiler: could not determine the type of this expression at callback

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm receiving `WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression` when I use `.apply` at a param callback. Lets me exemplify it. I have this code:

```
/**
 * @param {function(... [*])} callback
 * @param {string} name
 */
function call(callback, name) {
    return callback.apply(null, [name]);
    //     ^- error here.
}
```

In my code, I need `.apply` on a `callback` set on param and get what it returns. But Closure Compiler give me it error. I need run it with `java -jar compiler.jar --js test.js --js_output_file test.min.js --warning_level VERBOSE --jscom_warning reportUnknownTypes`.

Note that I force warning all unknow types, but `callback` types is `function(... [*])`, and it have an `.apply` method correctly (defined internally on CC because of your type). If I run code it works perfectly on browser.

Can it be a Closure Compiler bug, maybe?

**Things that I tried**

- `@param {*} callback`: error;
- `@param {function(*)} callback`: error;
- `return /** @type {function(... [*])} */ (callback).apply(null, [name]);`: error;
- `return (/** @type {function(... [*])} */ (callback)).apply(null, [name]);`: error;

Answer (score 1):

According with Concavel, on [**issue #1191**](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=1191) from Closure Compiler issue tracker, to `@param` a callback you need specify the callback returns like:

```
/** @param {function(*): number} callback */
```

It really solve the problem.